# iOS App Store bundle version comparison rules

Tags: ios, app-store, uploading

We are going to upload new version of our app to iOS App Store.

For previos version **CFBundleShortVersionString** was "1.9.2" and **CFBundleVersion** was "1.92.0". For current version we are going to use **CFBundleShortVersionString**:"1.10" and **CFBundleVersion**:"1.100.0".

But we afraid if App Store won't detect our 1.10 version as new. Won't it be recognized as older than previos version with CFBundleVersion:"1.92.0".

In other words, is **CFBundleVersion**:"1.100.0" will be higher than **CFBundleVersion**:"1.92.0" ?

Does anybody know how Apple compare **CFBundleVersion** parameter of uploaded builds?

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 1.100.0 is > 1.92.0. Apple uses semantic versioning.

From left to right, as long as none of the numbers are less than the new number, you are good.

For your example, the check goes something along the lines of (pseudo):

```
var oldVersionSems = "1.92.0".split(".")
var newVersionSems = "1.100.0".split(".")
var maxIndex = MIN(oldVersionSems.length, newVersionSems.length)
var isNewer = false
for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex, i++) {
    isNewer = newVersionSems[i] > oldVersionSems[i].toInt()
    if (isNewer) break
}
```

A good resource for how semantic versioning works is http://semver.org

Examples:

- 2.0.0 > 1.100.0
- 1.20.0 < 1.100.0
- 1.1.0 > 1.0.500
- 1.92.0 < 1.100.0

Comment: Thank you, Dan. We will try to use "1.100.0" for new version.

Comment: @Sergei can you please accept this answer if it is acceptable to you?

Comment: sure, we'll try to upload version and if this will work, I'll accept this answer. Because recently when we uploaded build with CFBundleVersion:"1.8" above build with CFBundleVersion:"1.7.3" App Store didn't recognize "1.8" as a new build, and we had to upload new build with CFBundleVersion:"1.80.1" to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: That is really strange that Apple didn't recognize that as a new build. Was the new build number updated as well? Apple also requires the build number to be advanced, so make sure that you have advanced that as well.

Comment: Yes, build number was also updated, CFBundleShortVersionString had value "1.8". But anyway for some reason Apple didn't recognize this build as a new version. That's why now we wonder if build with CFBundleVersion:"1.100.0" will be higher than build with CFBundleVersion:"1.92.0". I'll write here when we will upload new build and see the result.